# What exactly is byte[] in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, byte

In C#, byte is the data type for 8-bit unsigned integers, so a byte[] should be an array of integers who are between 0 and 255, just like an char[] is an array of characters.

But most of time when I encounter byte[], I see byte[] is used as a contiguous chunk of memory for storing raw representation of data.

How do these two relate to each other?

thanks

Comment: *array* `T[]` is a contiguous chunk of `T` instances (if `T` is `struct`) or references (if `T` is class)

Comment: Eventually everything is a set of bytes. You are mixing two things now: bytes as storage mechanism and representation of those bytes in data types.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5bdb6693.aspx

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_(computer_science)#Common_integral_data_types

Answer (score 2):

Well, a byte as datatype is exactly what you already said, an unsigned integer between 0 and 255. Furthermore this type needs exactly - believe it or not - one byte in your memory, thus also the name. This is why most readers that read byte per byte store those information in a structure that fits exactly the size of a byte - the `byte`-datatype.